# cvCaptureFromCAM

Tags: ros, opencv, openni-kinect, opencv2.2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello There, I am trying to save a stream of images from KInect camera. MY first line of code is:
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1)

I passed -1 so that It can search for the camera because I don't know the index for KInect Camera. Can someone help me find out what it is or another method used in the past.
Many thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10721/cvcapturefromcam/) by [robwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/751/robwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you use the openni_kinect node to publish the data from the kinect, you could subscribe to one of the camera topics(/camera/rgb/image_color or /camera/rgb/image_mono).
this would give you and image message which can be converted to an opencv iplimage using the cv_bridge package ([http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge)](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge)

---

Originally posted by [Bram van de Klundert](https://answers.ros.org/users/392/bram-van-de-klundert/) with karma: 241 on 2011-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2